# Creating a JSON result from mysql

Tags: php, arrays, json

How to create this type of json?:

```
{
     "Southern", "1040",
     "South-West": "710",
     "South-East": "692",
     "Western": "638",
     "North-Western", "448",
     "Eastern": "80",
     "North-East": "9"
}
```

I tried this way but you do not get that you need:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,"query"); 

       $json_response = array();

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
            array_push($json_response,array($row[0],$row[1]));
        }
```

Comment: What's the difference between your output and the desired output?

Comment: Are you talking about the format not being right? What result are you getting?

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs with `mysqli_query` and `MYSQL_NUM`

Comment: Receives this:
([["Southern","1040"],["South-West","710"],["South-East","695"],["Western","638"],["North-Western","448"],["Eastern","80"],["North-East","9"]])

How to convert to the correct json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from your attempt that each row has 2 columns with the data for example?

```
column1        column2
"southern"     "1040"
```

If so, just tweak how you build the array:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($db,"query"); 

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $data[$row[0]] = $row[1];
    }
    $json_response = json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply get an array from your query and encode it:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db,"query"); 
$json_response = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($json_response);
// OR
echo json_encode($json_response,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

**For reference:**

[mysqli.query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)
It returns an object, [mysqli-result object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php), then use [mysqli_fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) that returns an array which is encoded by [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function.

Comment: This way I know. I would like to get the JSON in the form...
`{
     "Southern":"1040",
     "South-West": "710",
     "South-East": "692",
     "Western": "638",
     "North-Western", "448",
     "Eastern": "80",
     "North-East": "9"
}`

Comment: As I understand, `Southern`, for example, is a field in your database table and `1040` is its value. So, the way I regard should give the result you want.

Comment: The result of your code is as follows:
`[["Southern","1040"],["South-West","710"],["South-East","695"],["Western","638"‌​],["North-Western","448"],["Eastern","80"],["North-East","9"]]`

Comment: Well, you may use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` as a parameter in `json_encode()`

Comment: This method does not work on the server:
`if($db = @mysqli_connect('mysql01xxxx','log','pass')){
       mysqli_select_db($db, '_mybase');
       
  $result = mysqli_query($db,"query"); 
  $json_response = $result->fetch_all(); 
}
 else{
  die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
 }  
  mysqli_close($db);
  echo json_encode($json_response);`

Comment: Well, there are object oriented style and procedural style for using mysqli, so we will uniform the style we use. checkout the edited answer.

Comment: You also may need the second parameter of `mysqli_fetch_all` to fine tune the result to be associative array. so set it as `MYSQLI_ASSOC`